# Adding Different Padding values on lightning:layoutItem

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

Is there a way to apply more than one padding value to the `lightning:layoutItem` component? The examples in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layoutItem/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleLayoutItems) only show one value:

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
```

I've tried extending this to additional values, but these don't seem to work:

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small bottom-none">
```

What can you do if you want the padding property to have different values?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't, however, you can declare a class attribute and further add custom CSS to the Item or to the child elements to fit your requirement).

Additionally, the documentation provides the set of allowed values:

> Sets padding to either the right and left sides of a container, or all sides of a container. Allowed values are horizontal-small, horizontal-medium, horizontal-large, around-small, around-medium, around-large.

Comment: For example: <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" class="slds-p-bottom_large">